# In Sql using UNIQUE

Tags: sql

I wrote a "Find sids who made exactly one reservation" query with a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause like this:

```
SELECT
  R.sid 
FROM
  Sailors S,
  Reserve R 
WHERE  
  R.sid = S.sid 
GROUP BY 
  R.sid 
HAVING 
  Count(R.sid) = 1
```

But I want to also find it by using `unique` command.  My friend asked me but I can't solve it.  We don't use group by.  We solve it with unique.  I tried but i can't solve it.  Can you help me?

Comment: Do you mean distinct instead of unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT UNIQUE` doesn't do what you want. In Oracle it's the same as `SELECT DISTINCT`. It doesn't find the unique rows. It removes the duplicates.

You have to use `GROUP BY ... HAVING ...`.

Comment: UNIQUE means the same as DISTINCT on older versions of Oracle, but in most DBMS's it does not exist as a query construct and is only used as a constraint in the CREATE/ALTER TABLE statements.

DISTINCT will not help you answer this question since it would return only one entry and your GROUPBY/HAVING would confuse its return, thinking that all sailors with at least one reservation has only one reservation, when they may in fact have many. 

your query is good as is.